# Facebook Graph API: get all posts and shared links from own wall

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have some problem with Facebook Graph API.

I have to get last 100 posts from own wall and I have to see all shared links from posts and "likes" of post. I try to use `https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/user/feed` request link but I get posts without additional info:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "message": "google.com",
      "created_time": "2017-03-24T15:24:21+0000",
      "id": "806657239481548_824418764372062"
    },
    {
      "story": "Vladimir  Grichenko shared a link.",
      "created_time": "2017-03-23T16:19:45+0000",
      "id": "806657239481548_823904527756819"
    },
    {
      "story": "Vladimir  Grichenko shared a link.",
      "created_time": "2017-01-19T15:50:55+0000",
      "id": "806657239481548_787402548073684"
    },
    {
      "story": "Vladimir  Grichenko updated his profile picture.",
      "created_time": "2016-03-28T16:01:43+0000",
      "id": "806657239481548_638636656283608"
    }
 ]
}
```

Can somebody help? I want to have more info about post. Thank you!

Comment: You probably need to get each post by its id.

Comment: _“but I get posts without additional info”_ – that’s likely because you neglected to _ask_ for any additional info in your API request - see the duplicate, that explains the issue.